# How do I set the format by the classmethod "setFormat" in main?

Tags: java

How do I set the format for a date by my classmethod "setFormat" in main? I have a test file where I write "d1.toString();" and other things Before. What I want is to be able to set the date format to either american format or Swedish format in the test file and see the result.

```
    public static void setFormat(int theFormat)
    {

        format = theFormat;

    }

    public String toString()
    {


        if(format == SE_FORMAT)
        {
            date2 = Integer.toString(Year) + '-' + Integer.toString(Month) + '-' + Integer.toString(Day);
        }
        else if(theFormat == US_FORMAT)
        {
            date2 =  Integer.toString(Month) + '/' + Integer.toString(Day)  + '/' + Integer.toString(Year);
        }
        else
        {
            date2 = Integer.toString(Year) + '-' + Integer.toString(Month) + '-' + Integer.toString(Day);
        }

        return date2;

    }
```

Comment: `SomeClass.setFormat(SomeClass.US_FORMAT)`

Comment: If the code above compiles, `date2` can only be `String`.

Comment: this `static` is a code smell, can we see your "main"